# How do you solve the below integration?

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I had to solve a long integration question and after simplification, it comes down to this:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(m\sqrt{7.5-7.5\cos(t)}\right)(7.5 \cos⁡(t))\,dt.$$

I tried integration by parts but couldn't solve.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $1 - \cos(t) = 2 \sin(t/2)^2$.